# How do I allow input of strings in JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane, invalid-characters

If I want to allow input of an integer in JOptionPane, I would need

```
String something= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " ");
int x = Integer.parseInt(something);
```

However, this time I want to input string into the `JOptionPane` InputDialog. Is there any way similar to `int x = Integer.parseInt();` but works for the string?

And, how do I make an advance feature whereby the program will be able to detect error such as invalid input? Eg. when the user(s) input space and enter instead of a value or a word, or their answer is out of range.
So basically their answer is something like space or -99 when answer should be within 1 to 100.

I'm sorry if this sounds dumb, I am very new to programming.

Comment: You already get a ```String``` from the input dialog, why would you want to parse it into a ```String``` again?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a message:");
        boolean validMessage = false;
        do {
            if (isMessageEmpty(message)) {
                message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "No message entered! Enter a message:");
            } else {
                if (Integer.parseInt(message) > 100 || Integer.parseInt(message) < 0) {
                    message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Message not acceptable, please enter a valid message::");
                } else {
                    validMessage = true;
                }
            }
        } while (!validMessage);
    }

    private static boolean isMessageEmpty(String message) {
        return message.trim().isEmpty();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way similar to Int x = Integer.parseInt(); but works for the string?

To answer your first question, there is a way. Like @John Verner said, just use the string you get from `JOptionPane`! No need to do anything special to it.

> And, how do I make an advance feature whereby the program will be able to detect error such as invalid input?

Try using `Integer.parseInt();` on the string you get. If it throws and exception or the returned int isn't in the specified range, tell the user to input again.

For more information on catching exceptions, [click here.](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/)